# django templates Unclosed tag on line 10: 'if'. Looking for one of: endif

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am getting the following error message in my django template:
Unclosed tag on line 10: 'if'. Looking for one of: endif.

I use endif on line 20 to close the if category.  if pages is closed on line 16.  Not sure if it is a syntax issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Rango</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
    {% if category %}
            {{ category.name }}
    <ul>
    {% if pages %}
        {% for page in pages %}
        <li>    {{ page.title }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <strong>No Pages</strong>
    {% endif %}

    {% else %}
            <strong>The specified category does not exist!</strong>
    <% endif %}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: at last endif <% endif %} should be {% endif %}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last endif: `<% endif %}`

Answer (score 2):

In the last endif, you have ( instead of {

```
<% endif %}
```

to

```
{% endif %}
```